# Change default display resolution of remote desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a remote desktop computer without a monitor with the default display resolution set to 1024x768, but I need the default resolution to be 1920x1080.

When I try to change the display resolution in settings>display, the message "keep the changes" shows up, but it reverts to 1024x768 after I select "keep changes." (The screen resolution never changes.)

All the information I found online suggests updating the screen drivers, but I don't have a monitor; I connect remotely.

How can I change the default resolution to 1920x1080, regardless of what software they use to remote in?

Comment: Does this host have the appropriate display drivers installed? The Microsoft Basic Adapter display drivers are likely the issue.

Comment: After updating Microsoft Basic Adapter drivers, I got an error code 43, and the screen got smaller. I'll try restarting the system to see if it changes.

Comment: You updated the Basic Display drivers despite the fact they are the source of your issue? My last comment was suggesting you need AMD/Nvidia/Intel display drivers not the Microsoft Basic Display drivers installed

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. I thought the Basic Display drivers had to be updated. 
I'll try different drivers now, thank you.